# inherit from 2 class

Tags: php, inheritance

this is abstract view

```
<?php
abstract class Abstract_View
{
     abstract function render($name);
}
?>
```

this is view

```
class View extends Abstract_View
{
function render($name)
{
    require __DIR__.'/../views/header.php';
    require __DIR__.'/../views/'.$name.'.php';//jaye $name masaln miad index/index
    require __DIR__.'/../views/header.php';
}
}
```

in my controller class i instatiate from view class to other classes for use view class inherit from controller class

```
<?php
class Controller 
{
function __construct()
{
    $this->view = new View();
}
}
```

i created a abstract class for index controller

```
<?php
abstract class Abstract_Index
{
abstract function index();
}
?>
```

and this is index:

```
<?php
class Index extends Controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
public function index(){
    $this->view->render('index/index');
}
}
```

and my problem is i must inherit from Controller for using object view and i have to inherit form Abstract Index and how to inherit from two class and this is correct?

Comment: Look into traits (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: You can refer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13966131/7789884

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Multiple Inheritance with Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966054/php-multiple-inheritance-with-interfaces)

Comment: Your `Abstract_Index` class looks more like an [`interface`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) to me.

Comment: @axiac could you tell me why it is interface?

Comment: You have created some abstract and concrete classes probably because this is how you learned from a tutorial. Now step back and think what's the responsibility of each class. Does `Abstract_Index` encapsulates behaviour that is common to all classes that extend it? Is there such common behaviour and you need to encapsulate it in a single class? In its current status, the `Abstract_Index` class is just an interface. It declares a method and that's all it does (no properties, no implementation). *(If you ask me you probably don't need it at all but this is another topic.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abstract class Abstract_Index extends Controller

class Index extends Abstract_Index
```

That should work.

Also delete the constructor, as it does nothing but call the parent constructor. Absence of a constructor means the parent one will be called by default.

Or, since the `index()` method is abstract, maybe just make it an interface?

```
<?php

interface IndexableInterface
{
    public function index();
}
```

Then implement it.

```
<?php 

class Index extends Controller implements IndexableInterface
{
    public function index()
    {
        // etc
    }
}
```